# Twitter API to find most common retweeter

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to use the Twitter API to search user "A"'s tweets and find the account that retweeted "User A"'s tweets the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `statuses/retweets_of_me` if you you have user "A"'s token and secret (he is using your app).

Alternatively you can use `statuses/mentions` to find all tweets containing `RT @A ....`  "A"'s retweets and count them manually.